# how can i display my posts alphabetically?

Tags: posts, categories

I want to order my posts alphabetically but I don't know how I can do it with my code. This is my code.

```
<div class="row">

        <div class="large-6 medium-12 small-12 columns">
            <h3>Elektrotechniek</h3>

            <?php query_posts('category_name=elektrotechniek');
            if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="opleiding-blok">

                            <div class="large-6 medium-6 small-12 columns">
                                <div class="opleiding-image"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="large-6 medium-6 small-12 columns no-padding-left">
                                <div class="opleiding-content">
                                    <div class="opleiding-titel">
                                        <h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="opleiding-knop">
                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="button-opleidingen groot" title="Lees verder">Meer Info...</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

            <?php endwhile;
            endif;
            wp_reset_query(); ?>

        </div>

</div>
```

can somebody help me, Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Add both `orderby` and `order` query parameters.

Here is an excerpt of the PHP code you need:

```
$query_args = array(
    "category_name" => "elektrotechniek",
    "orderby" => "post_title",
    "order" => "ASC"
);
```

Use `post_title` in case you need to order your posts by title, or `post_name`in case you prefer to order your posts by slug. Any other field of the `wp_posts` table can be used to order the posts by.

If you don't add `ASC` as the `order` value, WordPress orders the posts in a descendant way.